# android byte array buffers and performance?

Tags: android, performance, buffer, wav, audiotrack

i want to load wav files from an external location (sdcard) and play them using a single AudioTrack (streaming mode).

because it takes time to read the file and fill a byte array with the data i had the idea of creating an array for each sound (onCreate or something), then feeding that into the AudioTrack when its needed.

is this going to affect performance?
how is this array stored, will it use up some of the 'live' memory?

do you know of another way to do this, or any example i can look at?

thank you for your time and hopefully your answer